# Como fazer para que o NextJs não retorne as props antes que o getStaticProps tenha completado todas as requisições (promises)?

Tags: react, firebase, promises, next.js, async-await

Dentro da função getStaticProps eu pego alguns dados do banco de dados e realizo neles algumas tratamentos para se adequar a forma com que vou usar eles. Tudo acontece exatamente como deveria, exceto que o javascript não esta esperando a resolução de uma promise.

```
await realtime
    .ref( '/produtos/' )
    .once( 'value', async ( snapshot ) => {
      // pega todos os dados do arquivo produto se existir

      if ( snapshot.exists() ) {
        // ... Realizo aqui algumas transformações no formato dos dados ... //
        // ...

        const vetPromise = await criarArrayDePromisesDasImagens( produtos )

        produtos = await Promise.all( vetPromise ).then( ( values ) => { // resolve todas as promisses e então coloca o resultado das imagens no produto
          // Pega url atual da imagem no Firestore e armazena no mesmo local que antes tinha apenas uma url estatica do google, "gs://..."
          const result = porAsImagensNosProdutos( values, produtos )
          return result
        } )
      } else console.log( 'Dados não existentes' )
    } )
```

Ao chamar `await Promise.all()` o bloco de este bloco trava aqui enquanto a promise não é resolvida, entretanto nesse momento a execução sai da callback do `realtime.ref().once()` e volta para o escopo da `getStaticProps` e, portanto, retorna as minhas props sem que a promise tenha retornado os dados corretos, vai com os dados estáticos da imagem do firestore e não com a url recebida pelo metodo `pegarImagem()` que tem as seguintes instruções:

```
let refUrl = refFromURL('gs://...')
let url = refUrl.getDownloadURL()
```

O meu `getStaticProps` está dessa maneira:

```
async function criarArrayDePromisesDasImagens( produtos ) : Promise<Promise<string>[]> {
  //...
  async function criarArrayDePromisesDasImagens( produtos ) : Promise<Promise<string>[]> {
      const promisses = []

      produtos.forEach( ( produto ) => {
        produto.item.forEach( async ( value ) => {
          const keyItem = Object.keys( value )[ 0 ]
          const imagem = value[ keyItem ].images[ 0 ]
          const urlRef = storage.refFromURL( imagem )
          const url = pegarImagem( urlRef ) // url recebe uma promisse pendente
          promisses.push( url ) // adiciona uma promisse ao vetor
        } )
    } )
    return promisses // retorna um vetor de promisses
  }

  // Nessa função todas as imagens recebidas dentro do vetor são retornadas ao seu local de origem
  function porAsImagensNosProdutos( vetpromisses: Array<string>, arrayProdutos: ProdutosType ) {
    const value = arrayProdutos
    const aux = 0
    value.forEach( ( produto, indexProduto ) => {
      produto.item.forEach( async ( itemValue, keyValue ) => {
        const keyItem = Object.keys( itemValue )[ 0 ]
        value[ indexProduto ].item[ keyValue ][ keyItem ].images[ 0 ] = vetpromisses[ aux ]
        // produtos[0].item[0]["-MhxS6SS7yWaysPCATX2"].images[0] = "url da imagem"
      } )
    } )
    return value
  }

    // Parte do codigo do realtime que foi mostrado anteriormente
    // await realtime.ref( '/produtos/' ).once( 'value', async ( snapshot ) => { ... }

  return {
    props: {
      produtos,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, após uma boa noite de sono acordando de 30 em 30 minutos com a mesma pergunta em mente, eu resolvi retornar usar a callback do firebase apenas para tratar os dados e fiz a parte de resgatar as imagens fora desta callback. A principio resolve o problema de retornar as props antes que as promises sejam resolvidas, porém ainda não sei qual o motivo do `async/await` não ter funcionado como eu gostaria. Pelo que eu percebo, o bloco `await realtime.ref().onde('value', async snapshot => {...} )`  não espera todas as promises resolverem e o código continua a rodar na linha imediatamente após esse esse bloco,ou seja, no `return {props}`.
Embora não entenda direito o que aconteceu, esta foi a minha solução para o problema:

```
// após o calback da função once do firebase, quero que todas as url estaticas do google sejam tranformadas em urls do dominio firebasestorage.googleapis.com
  try {
    // Pega url atual da imagem no Firestore e armazena no mesmo local que antes tinha apenas uma url estatica do google, "gs://..."
    console.log( 'Veio até aqui' )
    const vetPromise = await criarArrayDePromisesDasImagens( produtos )

    produtos = await Promise.all( vetPromise ).then( ( values ) => { // resolve todas as promisses e então coloca o resultado das imagens no produto
      const result = porAsImagensNosProdutos( values, produtos )
      console.log( 'Imagens resgatadas, promise sucess' )
      return result
    } )
    console.log( 'produtos promise all =>', JSON.stringify( produtos, null, 4 ) )
  } catch ( error ) {
    global.console.log( 'erro ao capturar promises => ', error )
  }
```